# Service worker js file doesn't show on Chrome dev tools network tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker, workbox

I am trying to see the request the browser does to get the service worker implementation, but it doesn't show at all. I know for sure that my app has a working service worker, but I would like to be able to see that request on the network tab.

Is it possible? Is there a reason for it not to appear by default?

PS: I am not talking about the requests that the SW cache. I am talking about the browser getting the SW itself.

Comment: Please see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1335463

Comment: @JeffPosnick, maybe this should have a proper answer which can then be accepted, something like "Known bug, might get fixed one day if important people complain loudly enough"?

Comment: Not sure why the service worker registration shouldn't appear in DevTools. Maybe tools like https://mitmproxy.org/ or ngrok could help you in debugging the network request you are looking for.